# Unknown Byte Received

Tags: c#, ipv4, packet-capture

Capturing IP Packets by my own BitReader ( Reading Bit By Bit )

```
public class BitReader
{
    int Index;
    byte Current;
    Stream Reader;

    public BitReader ( Stream Memory )
    {
        Reader = Memory;
    }

    public bool? ReadBit ( )
    {
        if ( Index == 8 )
        {
            Index = 0;
            Current = ( byte ) Reader . ReadByte ( );
        }

        if ( Current == -1 )
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {

            return ( Current & ( 1 << ( 7 - Index++ ) ) ) != 0;
         // return ( Current & ( 1 << Index++ ) ) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Receiving a ZERO unknown byte in front of IP v4 Packets, as shown below,

> **00000000** 01000101 00000000 00000101 11000000 01001001 00100110
>   01000000 00000000 10000000 00000110 10110010 01111110 11000000
>   10101000 00000001 00001010 01000101 10101011 11110010 00110101

---

Edit 2 :

```
private byte [ ] Buffer = new byte [ 4096 ];

                    _Socket = new Socket ( AddressFamily . InterNetwork , SocketType . Raw , ProtocolType . IP );

                    _Socket . Bind ( new IPEndPoint ( IPAddress . Parse ( Interface . Text ) , 0 ) );

                    _Socket . SetSocketOption ( SocketOptionLevel . IP , SocketOptionName . HeaderIncluded , true );

                    _Socket . IOControl ( IOControlCode . ReceiveAll , BitConverter . GetBytes ( 1 ) , BitConverter . GetBytes ( 1 ) );

                    _Socket . BeginReceive ( Buffer , 0 , Buffer . Length , SocketFlags . None , new AsyncCallback ( OnReceive ) , null );
```

---

Edit 1 :

```
MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream ( Buffer , 0 , Length );
BitReader _BitReader = new BitReader ( _MemoryStream );

            for ( int Loop = 0 ; Loop < 21 ; Loop++ )
            {
                bool? Result = _BitReader . ReadBit ( );

                if ( Loop % 8 == 0 && Loop != 0 )
                {
                    myTextBox . Invoke ( new Action ( delegate { myTextBox . Text += " "; } ) );
                }

                if ( Result . HasValue )
                {
                    myTextBox . Invoke ( new Action ( delegate { myTextBox . Text += Result . Value ? 1 : 0; } ) );
                }
            }
```

---

Edit 3 :

```
MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream(Buffer, 0, Length);
BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new BinaryReader(_MemoryStream );
private byte VersionAndHeaderLength;
VersionAndHeaderLength = _BinaryReader.ReadByte();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with `Index == 0` and only read the next byte when `Index == 8`. This means that the first byte you read will be always zero. To fix this, set `Index = 8` in your constructor.

Also, since `byte` can never be -1, the condition that checks whether `Current == -1` will be always `false` and you will get infinite `1`s at the end of the file, because that's what you get when converting `-1` to `byte`.

Comment: Thanks very much I just figured out you answer and changed it to         `if ( Index % 8 = 0 )`

Comment: By the way -1 is just the **EOS** _End Of Stream_ Flag & I'm just checking it, Please provide your suggestion to this point ?